# Esconder div após teclado ser aberto. HTML

Tags: html, angular, ionic, ionic4

Boa noite!
Estou desenvolvendo um app utilizando Ionic / Angular, mas estou com um problema.
Ao clicar no teclado, os elementos do formulário, sobrescrevem o menu e o logotipo.

Desejo ocultar as divs responsáveis pela exibição do menu e do logotipo, estou usando no html:

```html
<div class="container top" [hidden]="keyboard.isVisible" >
```

Porém só está ocultando as divs, ao digitar algo usando o teclado e não ao clicar no input como era esperado.

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Quando abre o teclado a div não é escondida? Só quando começa a digitar algo?

Comment: Exatamente sam! O esperado era ao clicar, já esconder.

Comment: tenta setar uma boolean pra true no focus do input

Answer (score 1):

seta um `ngmodel` nos seus forms field `#formfield`

```
<div class="container top" *ngif="!formfield.focused" >
```

Algo nessa linha de quando os `formfield` forem focados, sua `div` não aparece.

Comment: SEU CONTAINER 

<div class="container top" *ngif="!formfield.focused" >

Comment: @RenanMartins na verdade responde sim, eu como usuário de Angular e de Ionic digo que é este um provavel caminho, claro que ele poderia ter escrito o que colocou no comentário, mas é provavel falta de experiencia em responder perguntas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ok